# Why don't Korach and his followers ask if an all Techeiles Beged is Patur from Techeiles?

Tags: tzitzis, moshe-rabbeinu, techeles, bamidbar-numbers-book-of, parshat-korach

> [רש"י במדבר ט"ז:א' ד"ה דתן ואבירם.](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he) ... מֶה עָשָׂה? עָמַד וְכָנַס ר"נ רָאשֵׁי סַנְהֶדְרָאוֹת — ... וְהִלְבִּישָׁן טַלִּיתוֹת שֶׁכֻּלָּן תְּכֵלֶת, בָּאוּ וְעָמְדוּ לִפְנֵי מֹשֶׁה, אָמְרוּ לוֹ טַלִּית שֶׁכֻּלָּהּ שֶׁל תְּכֵלֶת חַיֶּבֶת בְּצִיצִית אוֹ פְטוּרָה? אָמַר לָהֶם חַיֶּבֶת, הִתְחִילוּ לִשְׂחׂק עָלָיו, אֶפְשָׁר טַלִּית שֶׁל מִן אַחֵר חוּט אֶחָד שֶׁל תְּכֵלֶת פּוֹטְרָהּ, זוּ שֶׁכֻּלָּהּ תְּכֵלֶת לֹא תִפְטוֹר אֶת עַצְמָהּ?! (תנחומא):
>
> ... What did he [Korach] do? He arose and assembled 250 men, fitted to be heads of the Sanhedrin... and he attired them in robes of pure purple wool. They then came and stood before Moses and said to him, “Is a garment that is entirely of purple subject to the law of Zizith or is it exempt”? He replied to them: “It is subject to that law”. Whereupon they began to jeer at him: “Is this possible? A robe of any different coloured material, one thread of purple attached to it exempts it, and this that is entirely of purple should it not exempt itself (i.e. ipso facto be exempt) from the law of “Zizith”? (Midrash Tanchuma, Korach 2).

Why are Korach and his followers asking whether it is Chayav in Tzitzis? There is no reason why it shouldn't be Chayav in Tzitzis (strings at the corner). All that they've proved is that it should be Patur from Techeiles. Why don't they ask him whether a Beged that is completely Techeles should be Chayav in having Techeiles strings?

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbbe has a Sicha that addresses this question. I can't remember the details, but I think it is this one: http://wikisicha.com/tiki-index.php?page=Vol+8.11+-+Korach+1&structure=Contents+by+Parshiot . Also see R' Jonathan Sacks take on it here: 
 http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/1880794/jewish/The-Leader-as-Servant.htm

Comment: Often the Talmud calls the whole fringe "Tekhelet". Seemingly, the loose interchange of the names is based on a perspective that they are one Mitzva, not like we tend to think of them as "Tzitzit" and "Tzitzit+Tekhelet". Wearing just white is sorta like wearing just your Tefillin shel Rosh because your arm is in a cast. Yes, that's what you have to do and you get some reward, but you're really missing out on the full experience of Tefillin.

Comment: @Menachem Rabbi Jonathan Sacks' essay does not address this question.

Comment: @Eliya _the Midrash shows how Korach challenged the basis of Moses’ & Aaron’s leadership. The Israelites were “all holy; & G‑d is among them.” They were like a robe, every thread of which is royal blue. And just as a blue robe does not need an additional fringe to make it bluer still, so a holy people does not need extra-holy people like Moses & Aaron to make it holier still. The idea of a leadership hierarchy in “a kingdom of priests....” is a contradiction in terms. Everyone is like a priest. Everyone is holy. Everyone is equal in dignity before G‑d. Hierarchy has no place in such a nation._

Comment: @menachem The logic he uses only explains why it shouldn't need Techeiles.

Comment: The point was that *psil techeiles* is what makes it *holy*, thus, if there is no techeiles required (as "explained" by Korach), then it would not require any tzitzis at all.

Answer (score 3):

While it is impossible to know with certainty what the Tanhuma was thinking, I think that the following is a likely explanation.

Numbers (15:38-9) states:

> וְעָשׂוּ לָהֶם צִיצִת עַל-כַּנְפֵי בִגְדֵיהֶם, לְדֹרֹתָם; וְנָתְנוּ עַל-צִיצִת הַכָּנָף, פְּתִיל תְּכֵלֶת: וְהָיָה לָכֶם, לְצִיצִת, וּרְאִיתֶם אֹתוֹ וּזְכַרְתֶּם אֶת-כָּל-מִצְו‍ֹת יְהוָה, וַעֲשִׂיתֶם אֹתָם
>
> That they make them throughout their generations fringes in the
>   corners of their garments, and that they put with the fringe of each
>   corner a thread of blue.
>
> And it shall be unto you for a fringe, that ye may look upon it, and
>   remember all the commandments of the LORD, and do them.

After describing the tekhelet, verse 39 states that *it* shall be tsitsit, and you shall see *it* and remember all the mitsvot.

This could be interpreted as saying that the tekhelet in particular serves as the reminder of all the mitsvot.

Now, this remembering of the mitsvot is presented as being the reason for the mitsvah. It seems likely that the originator of the arguement regarding a garment fully dyed tekhelet, read the verses thusly. Accordingly, since the whole reason for the mitsva is remembering the mitsvot, and since it is particularly the tekhelet which serves this purpose, it follows that a fully dyed garment should be fully exempt from the entire mitsvah! Not just just from tekhelet.

---

There is some corroboration for the above reading of the verses (although not evidence that this was the reading of the originator of the above argument) see the commentary of Rashbam [to verse 39](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.15.39?lang=he&p2=Rashbam_on_Numbers.16.1&lang2=he), who may be explaining that the singular *it* refers exclusively to the tekhelet:

> והיה לכם לציצית - [פתיל] הציצית הזה יהיה לכם לראייה שתראו אותו. כמו מציץ מן החרכים. וכן מצאתי בסיפרי. [וגם] פתיל תכלת פירשו רבותינו לפי שהתכלת דומה לים וים דומה לרקיע ורקיע לכסא הכבוד

However, I am not sure if that is his intent, and it is difficult to determine given different versions of this passage, (note Sefarias minor variations).

Comment: Note also the Zohar: זוהר כרך ב (שמות) פרשת תרומה דף קנב עמוד ב: 
מאן גרים לון לדחלא מקמי קודשא בריך הוא ההוא נחש ההיא רצועה דמסתכלן בה, אוף הכי תכלת (במדבר טו) וראיתם אותו וזכרתם את כל מצות יי'

Comment: It should be noted that many other Hazalic passages are bothered by singular usage in the verse, and give varying explanations, e.g. the Sifrei: ספרי במדבר פרשת שלח פיסקא קטו:  
ר' מאיר אומר וראיתם אותם לא נאמר כאן אלא וראיתם אותו מגיד הכתוב שכל המקיים מצות ציצית מעלים עליו כאלו הקביל פני שכינה שהתכלת

Answer (score 2):

This interestingly phrased question of Korach appears in two other sources.

[**Badmibar Rabbah** 18:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.18?lang=he)

> קָפַץ קֹרַח וְאָמַר לְמשֶׁה טַלִּית שֶׁכֻּלָּהּ תְּכֵלֶת מַהוּ שֶׁתְּהֵא פְּטוּרָה מִן הַצִּיצִית, אָמַר לוֹ חַיֶּיבֶת בְּצִיצִית. אָמַר לוֹ קֹרַח טַלִית שֶׁכֻּלָּהּ תְּכֵלֶת אֵין פּוֹטֶרֶת עַצְמָהּ, אַרְבָּעָה חוּטִין פּוֹטְרוֹת אוֹתָהּ

As well as [**Yerushalmi Sanhedrin** 10:1](https://sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Sanhedrin.50a.1?lang=he)

> עמד ועשה טלית שכולן תכלת אתא גבי משה א"ל משה רבינו טלית שכלה תכלת מה שתהא חייבת בציצית אמר לו חייבת דכתיב גדילים תעשה לך וגו'

In both places as well it says Korach asked if this garment is obligated in ***tzitzis***, where seemingly it being made of *techeiles* shouldn't make a difference to if it needs *tzitzis* or not. Your question is actually something that many commentaries were bothered by ([**Mizrachi**](https://www.sefaria.org/Mizrachi%2C_Numbers.16.1.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) to **Numbers** 16:1; [**Eitz Yosef**](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.18.3?lang=he&p2=Etz_Yosef_on_Bamidbar_Rabbah.18.3.1&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he) (quoting **Zayis Ra’anan**), [**Maharzu**](https://sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.18.3?lang=he&p2=Perush_Maharzu_on_Bamidbar_Rabbah.18.3&lang2=he), and **Chiddushei HaRashash** to **Bamidbar Rabbah**; **Eitz Yosef** (quoting **Zayis Ra’anan**) and **Biur HaAmarim** to **Midrash Tanchuma** *Korach* § 3; and it seems the **Korbon HaEidah** to **Yerushalmi Sanhedrin**).

Therefore, they explain that Korach wanted to know **if he needed to dye the *tzitzis* in his garment *techeiles*** or is the garment being that color sufficient. Moshe responded that he still needed to make some of the strings *techeiles*. This explanation fits better with Korach’s subsequent question, which is similar in nature: Does a house full of *scrolls* need a *scroll* on the doorpost, i.e. a *mezuzah*. What they have in common is I have X, why would I need another X. According to the plain meaning of the words, the two questions aren't as similar.

However, the [**Kesav Sofer**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14083&st=&pgnum=473) *ad. loc.* understands the *Midrash* according to its literal wording. He seems to interpret it like @mevaqesh suggested, that Korach felt that a garment full of *techeiles* accomplished the purpose of the *mitzvah* of *tzitzis*, so there was no point in adding *tzitzis* to it.

Now, this sounds like Korach is *doresh ta'amah dekra*, that he applies the reason behind the *mitzvah* to its laws. There are late *achronim* who explicitly suggest that this was Korach's opinion. It's actually a dispute if we are *doresh ta'amah dekra*, and some of these *achronim* suggest that this was the dispute between Korach and Moshe, where the latter held we aren't *doresh ta'amah dekra*. These *achronim* are, *inter alia*, [**Avnei Eliyahu**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=5528&st=&pgnum=192) *parshas Chukas s.v.* ובזה י"ל ‎[#1], [**Harei BaShamayim**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31954&st=&pgnum=39) *ad. loc. s.v.* במדרש מה ראה ‎[#2], **Chavatzeles HaSharon** *parshas Ki Seitzei s.v.* וסמך נחמד (although he provides an alternative explanation), and [**Chakel Yitzchak**](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=174186&pagenum=138) *parshas Korach s.v.* והנה לר' שמעון. If you look at these sources inside, you'll see some go with the literal understanding of the *Midrash*, and some go with the explanation of the above commentaries. Either way, it seems Korach was *doresh ta'amah dekrah*.